# Calling convention "defines" without #define

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, calling-convention

In Microsoft's WinDef.h several #defines for callbacks are introduced:

```
#ifdef _MAC
#define CALLBACK    PASCAL
#define WINAPI      CDECL
#define WINAPIV     CDECL
#define APIENTRY    WINAPI
#define APIPRIVATE  CDECL
#ifdef _68K_
#define PASCAL      __pascal
#else
#define PASCAL
#endif
#elif (_MSC_VER >= 800) || defined(_STDCALL_SUPPORTED)
#define CALLBACK    __stdcall
#define WINAPI      __stdcall
#define WINAPIV     __cdecl
#define APIENTRY    WINAPI
#define APIPRIVATE  __stdcall
#define PASCAL      __stdcall
#else
#define CALLBACK
#define WINAPI
#define WINAPIV
#define APIENTRY    WINAPI
#define APIPRIVATE
#define PASCAL      pascal
#endif
```

Is there a way to do something like that without preprocessor macros?
I would like to have something, that resolves to different calling conventions on Unix and Windows, but which - unlike a macro - can be namespaced.

I have tried "typedef __stdcall test;" but that doesn't compile.

EDIT - here is an example usage scenario:

```
namespace Thread
{
    typedef startRoutineReturnType (startRoutineCallingConvention *startRoutineCallback)(void* pArg);
}

Thread::startRoutineReturnType Thread::startRoutineCallingConvention startRoutine(void* pArg);
```

This way startRoutine can confirm to the signature of that callback on all platforms although the calling convention of the callback differs between platforms.
When there is the possibility that a lot of functions have to confirm to that callback signature then something like

```
#ifdef UNIX
    void* foo(void* pArg)
#elif WINDOWS
    DWORD WINAPI foo(LPVOID pArg)
#else
    // something else
#endif
{
    // body
}
```

instead looks quite messy.

Comment: It's because `__stdcall` is not a type.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no such thing as a "namespaced text substitution" feature in C++.  The preprocessor doesn't know or care about namespaces.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Calling conventions are clearly not *namespaced*!

Comment: @cdhowie That's exactly why Kaiserludi doesn't want to use the preprocessor.

Comment: You can safely assume that, if this were possible, Microsoft would not use the preprocessor either.  These macros cause plenty of accidents.  It isn't possible.

Comment: @HansPassant I wouldn't be so sure. The WinAPI was built to work with C, not C++. That's why you don't find any polymorphism or templates in it. If a feature like this were to be added more recently, WinAPI would not reflect that.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Seems clear to me.  Kaiserludi said "I would like to have something that resolves ... which can be namespace", not "calling conventions can be namespaced".  Kaiserludi wants to be able to specify calling convention attributes without preprocesor macros. (And presumably conditionally; otherwise one could just use `__stdcall` and `__cdecl` directly.)

Comment: Why do you want a *calling convention* (meta data) to be namespaced?

Comment: @jamesdlin I'm not sure he has any other choice.  I don't know of any mechanisms other than macros that let you create aliases to function attributes.

Comment: @Hans Actually Microsoft uses an awful lot of Macros in cases where other language features would be more appropriate (probably because many of these macros are older than many language features and can't be changed for backwards compatibility reasons). For example Windows.h defines min/max macros, which introduce the problem, that something like std::min or std::max will be touched by the preprocessor, although that problem could have been avoided if MS would have used inline functions instead of macros.

Comment: I'm still trying to imagine how the OP thinks this could be used.  Can you put up some sample code showing how you would _use_ calling conventions in a namespace?

Comment: @Kaiserludi: Microsoft uses macros where features from *your language* might have been a better solution, but Microsoft wasn't using *your language* (where *your language* is anything other than C89) and so didn't have the option of using those features.

Comment: @Mark Simply to avoid that it may collide with anything else, which may have the same name.

Comment: In practice, you really shouldn't care about scoping and namespaces because you shouldn't have conflicts.  You should *expect* that anything named in all capital letters is a preprocessor macro.  Following that rule, the only time you should get a conflict is if you're defining your own macro with the same name.

Comment: @MooingDuck Kaiserludi doesn't necessarily want them in  *namespace*  but wants something *scoped* so that it doesn't conflict with other things that have the same name but are in a different scope.

Comment: @Ben: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. They often had no better alternative in C89, but in many cases that doesn't mean, that there also isn't any better alternative in C99 or in C++.

Comment: @Kaiserludi: But I'm not sure what can practically be done to improve this.  Are you proposing multiple versions of `windows.h`, one for C89, one for C99, one for C2011, one for C++98, one for C++11?  That would be a terrible maintenance burden.  Not to mention the effect on all the automated tools that parse the Windows header files and spit out import declarations for other languages.

Comment: @Ben: I just wanted to give an example to Hans, that "You can safely assume that, if this were possible, Microsoft would not use the preprocessor either." isn't necessarily true, because if I am not bound to the same restrictions like MS (conform with) in my code, then I may have alternative options, that they don't have.

Still what they could have done would have been to only use all uppercase names for macros.

Comment: @Mooing I have just provided an usage example in an edit.

Comment: @Kaiserludi: Your edit doesn't show why you need namespacing (or similar).  I don't think namespaced(or similar) conventions will actually change anything.

Comment: @Mooing Well, a CompanyNamespace::ProjectNamespace::Subnamespace::Thread::startRoutineCallingConvention obviously is much less likely to collide with anything else than just a startRoutineCallingConvention.
Of course I could also just call it startRoutineCallingConvention_PlusSomeAwfulLongUniqueIdentifier, but then I couldn't just use using directives to shorten things in places where no name collisions happen.

Answer (score 3):

It's a terrible hack in my opinion, but I tried seeing if I could do it with template specializations and it actually worked.  Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

enum CALLCONVENTION
{
    STDCALL,
    CDECL
};

template <CALLCONVENTION Convention>
void Function()
{
}

template<>
void __stdcall Function<STDCALL>()
{
    std::cout << "STDCALL" << std::endl;
}

template<>
void __cdecl Function<CDECL>()
{
    std::cout << "CDECL" << std::endl;
}

namespace StdCall
{
    void Foo()
    {
        Function<STDCALL>();
    }
}

namespace CDecl
{
    void Foo()
    {
        Function<CDECL>();
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    Function<STDCALL>();
    Function<CDECL>();
    StdCall::Foo();
    CDecl::Foo();

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles and works on Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Doesn’t seem like a hack to me. Static parameterisation is what templates are for, and since you can’t parameterise by calling convention, you just specialise instead.

Comment: I don't think that you have got what I mean.
I want to be able to use something like void Foo::callingConvention Function(){} and Foo::callingConvention should resolve to __cdecl, __stdcall or something else depending on the platform that I am compiling for.

Comment: Looking at the giant comment thread on your original post, I also don't really think there is a way to get platform specific code without using the preprocessor.  The easiest way would be to `#define CALLCONV __cdecl` or `#define CALLCONV /*__conv*/` based on your platform.  Then you can simply do `void CALLCONV Function(){}`

Comment: Yes, that's how I am currently doing it, but as you have read the comments on the question I think you know why I would prefer a scoped alternative if there should be one.
Upvoted "giant comment thread", because it made me laugh :-)

Comment: PS: well, I wouldn't mind something like
#ifdef WINDOWS
typedef __stdcall foo
#else
typedef __cdecl foo
#endif
That would stillbe  using the preprocessor to achieve the platform specific behavior, but that typedef would honor scopes.